# How to sync Tags to Labels with the RallyAPI and JIRA connector

Tags: ruby, jira, rally

I am using the RallyConnector to sync user stories and defects with JIRA.

https://help.rallydev.com/jira-5-installation-user-guide

here is my field mapping

```
<FieldMapping>
  <Field><Rally>Name</Rally>         <Other>Summary</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Description</Rally>  <Other>Description</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>FormattedID</Rally>  <Other>RallyKey</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Tags</Rally>  <Other>Labels</Other></Field>
</FieldMapping>
```

When I added the **Tags** field and map it to the **Labels** (JIRA's version of Tags) to the connector, I get the following error:

ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::JiraRestConnection.rescue in attempt_update - Attempt to update issue JM-25 failed, undefined method `split' for # < RallyAPI::RallyCollection:0x007fd1950b2890 @results=[]>

I suppose this has something to do with the fact that it is a list of values, and just not a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Bugzilla and CQ connectors support tags, but not the Jira connector. It's mentioned [here, in the Best Practices](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-integrations-faq-and-best-practices#Known-limitations). You are correct that in WS API Tags is a collection.